# Unable to target a selector using Namespace ,Modular, Private

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to target a jquery selector

by using namespaces in my script and also making function private but i think i am still missing something here, can anyone guide. It works if i try by adding a breakpoint on the last line and than use devtools to access MyUtility.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder()

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Selectors</title>


</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="test">First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<!--<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $('li.test').css('color','green')
    })
</script>-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var customModule = (function () {
        var MyUtility = {
            Selectors: {
                ColorCss: function () {
                    var myBorder = function () {
                        $('li').css('color', 'red')
                        console.log('hello')
                    }
                    return{
                        myBorder: myBorder
                    }
                }()
            }
        }
    }())
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just trying to understand the concept of namespaces,private etc - but shouldn't it work ?

Comment: There are no private or public methods in javascript, there's only scope.

Comment: @adeneo: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Even if Crockford calls them private, they really aren't, it's just variables being out of scope.

Comment: @ Purefan - you read my mind :)

Comment: if i try by adding a breakpoint on the last line and than use devtools to access MyUtility.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder() it works, can you advise on how to actually access it via script without breakpoint, i mean do i need to call it via document ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `It works if i try by adding a breakpoint on the last line and than use devtools to access MyUtility.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder()`

This is your code:

```
var customModule = (function () {
    var MyUtility = {
          Selectors: {
            ColorCss: function(){
                   var myBorder = function(){ 
                        $('li').css('color', 'red');
                        console.log('hello');
                   }
                   return{ myBorder: myBorder }
            }()
          } // Selectors
    } // MyUtility
}())
```

Your code above can be written as:

```
function myBorderFunc() { $('li').css('color', 'red'); console.log('hello');}
var selectorObj = { ColorCss : function(){ return{ myBorder: myBorderFunc } }()};
var MyUtility = { Selectors: selectorObj};
var customModule = ( function(){ MyUtility }() );
```

This shows the problem

1. `var customModule` is a function expression that does not return anything and it is therefore `undefined`
2. since `customModule` is undefined you can not use customModule.MyUtility
3. as you said you can call `MyUtility.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder()` since `MyUtility` is an object that has a property `Selectors` and so on

you can test it out with this example:

```
// undefined since nothing is returned
var bar = (function(){ {Foo: "i am foo"} }()); 

// returns foo and can be used bar.Foo ---> "i am foo"
var bar = (function(){ return {Foo: "i am foo"} }());
```

To 'fix your code' return `MyUtility`

```
var customModule = (function () {
    var MyUtility = {
          Selectors: {
            ColorCss: function(){
                   var myBorder = function(){ 
                        $('li').css('color', 'red');
                        console.log('hello');
                   }
                   return{ myBorder: myBorder }
            }()
          } // Selectors
    } // MyUtility
    return MyUtility;
}())
```

This way you can access it like this `customModule.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder()`.

More info about [Function expressions vs. Function declarations](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)

Comment: Great :) Thanks very much => return MyUtility => customModule.Selectors.ColorCss.myBorder()